# What are the variables involved in constructing an ROC curve?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc

Say I have a classifier and I achieve FAR of 10% and FRR of 15%. What would I need to do with these to construct an ROC curve?

I'm having trouble seeing what they actually represent and the situation in which they are used. I don't seem to have an important variable the shifts the FAR and FRR in one direction or the other. Can I still use ROC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: no, you cannot.

ROC curve is a parametric curve, you need a scalar value you can shift in order to change your classifiers decisions. Its usefull for:

- Checking robustness to this parameter
- fine-tuning final probability estimates for a particular application